# How do you feed a wolf?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I equip the porkchop and right click on the wolf, I eat it. If I left click, I beat him with it. If I drop it on the ground, he doesn't care.

How am I supposed to feed him?

edit: I did try both on SMP and on single player. Looks like I thought it wasn't working because apparently I arbitrarily decided that the raw ones healed the wolves more than the cooked ones, while they healed them so few that they didn't raise the tail.

I'll try again in SMP too as soon as I have the occasion, and let you know if it works there too.

Comment: Is this in SMP?

Comment: If you're gonna tame him: feed any bones (2-5) to the wolf until it gains a red collar and a short burst of hearts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I also have this problem and could only come up by accident with this partial solution. I hope it's not the actual way of doing it.

The problem is you need to have more than one porkchop in your inventory slot; then, when you right click on the dog, *two* porkchops will be consumed: the first by you, the second by the dog. You'll be able to see this is working because:

- You consume two porkchops per right click.
- The dog's tail raises.
- The dog does not toggle between sitting and standing stance (like it usually would do when "just" right clicking).

Basically:

1. Right click on dog to order him to sit.
2. Select porkchops.
3. Right click on dog until he stands up.

Now you have traded (a lot of) bacon for a fully healthy dog.

Comment: I thought that porkchops couldn't stack.

Comment: they don't, none of the food items do unless you're using a mod. I've never noticed two pork chops being consumed, but I haven't investigated it at all. Answer is correct though - put it in your quick slot and right click for a happy puppy

Comment: @Strix You're right. I've been trying to find a wolf to improve my answer but failed so far :/

Comment: How has feeding wolves changed post 1.8? Has it?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer — If nothing else, I think the double-consumption bug was fixed sometime between when this answer was written and the current release.  I don't have a reference for that, however.

Comment: @BenBlank. This answer was written may '11. I think it's safe to assume that this is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier for another player to feed your dogs in SMP, but you can still feed them yourself. It helps if you tell them to sit first.

You will still have to feed yourself - but now since food takes longer to eat you will know if you're feeing yourself vs the dog. The "double-consume bug" is gone due to the longer ingestion time.

You should see their tail go up, and if you have particles turned on, they will enter "love mode". It's hard to see the tail rise while they are sitting; the first few times you may end up right-clicking a lot to make sure you're doing it right.